# AWS SNS/SQS: How to deliver exactly one SNS message per one SQS subscriber?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Basically I have a SNS topic with multiple SQS subscribers. By default its sending out the same message to all subscribers but what I need is one message is sent to exactly one subscriber.

One solution come to my mind but I want to know if I'm leaving out any possible solutions.

```
Use `Message Group Id`
    A) Get all SQS subscribers for SNS topic
    B) When sending out list of messages, we randomly choose a SQS subscriber 
       id, and use that as `Message Group Id`
    C) When SNS message is received, it will go the appropriate SQS subscriber.
```

Is there any other solutions? for instance if I create a FIFO queue and attach subscribers, are they all getting the same messages?

Comment: Does [SNS Message Filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html) do what you need?

Comment: I ended up using MessageGroupID because I am dealing with intermediary SQS subscriptions to SNS

Comment: If you just wish to send a message to one recipient, why are you using an Amazon SQS queue? What type of subscriptions are you using (email, sms, etc)? And why would you want to send a message to a random subscriber?